# How to get the actual attachment size or total size of attached files

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi all I am having a DataTable where it holds filename with path as follows

```
String[] sizeArry = new String[] { "Byes", "KB", "MB" };

    String GetSize(ulong sizebytes, int index)
    {

        if (sizebytes < 1000) return sizebytes + sizeArry[index];

        else return GetSize(sizebytes / 1024, ++index);
    }

protected DataTable GetAttachment()
    {
        DataTable attachment = new DataTable();
        attachment.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
        attachment.Columns.Add("Attachment", typeof(string));
        attachment.Columns.Add("Size", typeof(string));

        attachment.Rows.Add(1, " files/abc.txt");
        attachment.Rows.Add(2, "files/test.pdf");

        foreach (DataRow row in attachment.Rows)
        {
            string sFilename = row["Attachment"].ToString();
            string path = Server.MapPath(sFilename);
            FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(path);
            row["Attachment"] = fi.Name;
            row["Size"] = GetSize((ulong)fi.Length, 0);
        }
        Total(attachment);
        return attachment;
    }
```

Which is giving me  the result as follows `abc.txt 3KB test.pdf 11MB` Now I need to sum up these sizes and need to show the size in a `label` so can some one help me. I tried as follows which is not working as per required

```
protected void Total(DataTable dt)
    {
        int size = 0;
        int cnt = 0;
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            cnt++;
            string s = row["Size"].ToString().Remove(row["Size"].ToString().Length - 2);
            size = size + Convert.ToInt16(s);
        }
       label.Text = cnt.ToString() + " attachments " + size.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: What does that mean, that it is not working as required? Sum is wrong? or?

Comment: Yes sum is wrong it is displaying `14mb` which is wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you have to check whether it is `Bytes`, `KiloBytes`, `MegaBytes` etc.

If you know what is it, you can call your helper methods, to convert from Bytes->KiloBytes->MegaBytes like this:

```
public static class Converter
{
    public static double ConvertBytesToMegabytes(long bytes)
    {
        return (bytes / 1024f) / 1024f;
    }

    public static double ConvertKilobytesToMegabytes(long kilobytes)
    {
        return kilobytes / 1024f;
    }  
}
```

Edit:

You do not have to count the number of rows, there is a property for that:

```
label = dt.Rows.Count +" attachments " + size.ToString();
```

Edit2:

Something like this could work.

```
protected void Total(DataTable dt)
{
    string label;
    double size = 0;

    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        var result = Regex.Match(row["Size"].ToString(),@"([0-9]+)(.*)");
        var fileSize = Convert.ToInt32(result.Groups[0].Value);
        var type = result.Groups[1].Value;

        switch (type)
        {
            case "B":
                size += ConvertBytesToMegabytes(fileSize);
                break;
            case "KB":
                size += ConvertKilobytesToMegabytes(fileSize);
                break;
            case "MB":
                size += fileSize;
                break;
            //ETC...
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
    label = dt.Rows.Count +" attachments " + size.ToString();       
}
```

Comment: but as per the datatable I have how I will know which method  I need to call

Comment: @Learner I've edited the answer... Not sure it will work for 100%, but you can get the idea from that